# MomentOfInertia for Polyhedra incorrectly computed?

Tags: regions, mesh, polyhedra

The moment of inertia for Regions seems to be wrongly calculated. Simple example:

```
PolyhedronData["Octahedron", "InertiaTensor"]*PolyhedronData["Octahedron", "Volume"] // MatrixForm
```

yields correctly (see also [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_moments_of_inertia))

```
{{1/(15 Sqrt[2]), 0, 0}, {0, 1/(15 Sqrt[2]), 0}, {0, 0, 1/(15 Sqrt[2])}}

(* N[,7] *)

{{0.04714045, 0, 0}, {0, 0.04714045, 0}, {0, 0, 0.04714045}}
```

However the function

```
MomentOfInertia[PolyhedronData["Octahedron", "Region"]]
```

yields incorrectly

```
{{0.0465585, 0., 0.}, {0., 0.0465585, 0.}, {0., 0., 0.0465585}}
```

I don't find a way to improve the accuracy of the Region function. The same accuracy problem persists for more complex shapes loaded from files. This makes the computation of the moment of inertia with Mathematica (tested with version 11.3.0.0) unreliable. Similar problem persist for

```
MomentOfInertia[PolyhedronData["Tetrahedron", "Region"]]
```

and

```
MomentOfInertia[PolyhedronData["Cube", "Region"]]
```

quits the kernel. Did anyone observe a similar behavior or knows how to increase the accuracy of Region computations?

Comment: Try using  the`"ImplicitRegion"` property rather than a mesh based one (which is where I believe the approximations are coming from).

Comment: @Tobias That (in particular the kernel quits) looks like a severe issue! You should report that to Wolfram Support.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Some ranting about the built-in implementation

Given that the inertia tensor is defined by [integrals of quadratic polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_of_inertia#Inertia_tensor) which can be easily evaluated *exactly* on each simplex of a `MeshRegion`, it is absolutely inacceptable that Mathematica uses inappropriate approximation formulae for the integrals.

As a temporary workaround: `PolyhedronData["Octahedron", "Region"]` is a `BoundaryMeshRegion`. One can discretize it into many small tetrahedra and compute `MomentOfInertia` of that tensor.

```
Itrue = PolyhedronData["Octahedron", "InertiaTensor"]* PolyhedronData["Octahedron", "Volume"];
R = PolyhedronData["Octahedron", "Region"];
S = DiscretizeRegion[R, MaxCellMeasure -> 0.00001];
Max[Abs[MomentOfInertia[R, RegionCentroid[R]] - Itrue]]
Max[Abs[MomentOfInertia[S, RegionCentroid[S]] - Itrue]]

0.000581981

9.66155*10^-9
```

So, the error is now much smaller, but it is still there (an the computations were done with a ridiculously large amount of effort).

## An alternative implementation

So, let's be constructive. A first step towards a more correct implementation could be the following. It uses a 4-point Gauss quadrature on tetrahedra (which is exact on polynomials up to order 2), so it will only work for simplicial regions. Other regions have to be discretized first. The method relies also on the tetrahedra and triangles of `MeshRegion`s and `BoundaryMeshRegion`s being consistently oriented (so this may be a potential source of bugs).

```
Quiet[Block[{PP, P, QQ, Q, r, X, A, quadraturepoints, quadratureweights, vol, integrand},
   PP = Table[Compile`GetElement[P, i, j], {i, 1, 4}, {j, 1, 3}];
   QQ = Table[Compile`GetElement[Q, j], {j, 1, 3}];
   r = {X[[1]], X[[2]], X[[3]]} - QQ;
   quadraturepoints = Table[Mean[PP] (1 - 1/Sqrt[5]) + PP[[i]]/Sqrt[5], {i, 1, 4}];
   vol = 1/3! Det[Table[PP[[i]] - PP[[1]], {i, 2, 4}]];
   quadratureweights = vol ConstantArray[1/4, 4];
   integrand = X \[Function] Evaluate[r.r IdentityMatrix[3] - TensorProduct[r, r]];
   getMomentOfInertia = 
    With[{code = N[quadratureweights.integrand /@ quadraturepoints]},
     Compile[{{P, _Real, 2}, {Q, _Real, 1}},
      code,
      CompilationTarget -> "C",
      RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
      Parallelization -> True,
      RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
      ]
     ];
   getMomentOfInertiaB =
    With[{code = -N[
         quadratureweights.integrand /@ quadraturepoints /. {
           Compile`GetElement[P, 4, 1] -> 0,
           Compile`GetElement[P, 4, 2] -> 0,
           Compile`GetElement[P, 4, 3] -> 0
           }
         ]},
     Compile[{{P, _Real, 2}, {Q, _Real, 1}},
      code,
      CompilationTarget -> "C",
      RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
      Parallelization -> True,
      RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
      ]
     ]
   ]
  ];

MyMomentOfInertia[R_MeshRegion?Region`Mesh`Utilities`SimplexMeshQ, 
   p_] := Total@getMomentOfInertia[
    Partition[
     MeshCoordinates[R][[
      Flatten[MeshCells[R, 3, "Multicells" -> True][[1, 1]]]]], 4],
    p
    ];

MyMomentOfInertia[R_MeshRegion, p_] := 
  MyMomentOfInertia[
   DiscretizeRegion[R, MaxCellMeasure -> ∞], p];

MyMomentOfInertia[R_MeshRegion] := 
  MyMomentOfInertia[R, RegionCentroid[R]];

MyMomentOfInertia[
   B_BoundaryMeshRegion?Region`Mesh`Utilities`SimplexMeshQ, p_] := 
  Total@getMomentOfInertiaB[
    Partition[
     MeshCoordinates[B][[
      Flatten[MeshCells[B, 2, "Multicells" -> True][[1, 1]]]]], 3],
    p
    ];

MyMomentOfInertia[B_BoundaryMeshRegion, p_] := 
  MyMomentOfInertia[
   DiscretizeRegion[B, MaxCellMeasure -> ∞], p];

MyMomentOfInertia[B_MeshRegion] := 
  MyMomentOfInertia[B, RegionCentroid[B]];
```

Here a usage example:

```
Itrue = PolyhedronData["Octahedron", "InertiaTensor"] PolyhedronData["Octahedron", "Volume"];
R = PolyhedronData["Octahedron", "Region"];
S = DiscretizeRegion[R, MaxCellMeasure -> ∞];
Max[Abs[MomentOfInertia[R] - Itrue]] // RepeatedTiming
Max[Abs[MomentOfInertia[S] - Itrue]] // RepeatedTiming

Max[Abs[MyMomentOfInertia[R] - Itrue]] // RepeatedTiming
Max[Abs[MyMomentOfInertia[S] - Itrue]] // RepeatedTiming
```

> {0.00164, 0.000581981}
>
> {0.0017, 0.000581981}
>
> {0.0000736, 6.93889*10^-18}
>
> {0.0000736, 2.08167*10^-17}

It is not only more accurate but also faster than the current implementation.

## Edit

Support just told me that the development team is informed. Let's await what happens in the upcoming versions...

Comment: Thanks, this works with fixed floating point precision, also for loaded triangle meshes. There is a small typo in the function MyMomentOfInertia[
   B_BoundaryMeshRegion...] you should replace R with B in MeshCoordinates[R] and MeshCells[R,...]

Comment: You're welcome. Also thanks for the hint to the typo! Fixed it.

Comment: Since the input region has inexact coordinates I think it does make sense to return an inexact answer.

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be more than just floating point error. The exact computation yields the same result:

```
Itrue = PolyhedronData["Octahedron", "InertiaTensor"] * PolyhedronData["Octahedron", "Volume"];

ebmr = BoundaryMeshRegion[##, WorkingPrecision -> ∞]& @@ PolyhedronData["Octahedron", "GraphicsComplex"];
Iexact = MomentOfInertia[ebmr]
```

> ```
> {{8 Sqrt[2]/243, 0, 0}, {0, 8 Sqrt[2]/243, 0}, {0, 0, 8 Sqrt[2]/243}}
> ```

```
Itrue - Iexact // Simplify
```

> ```
> {{1/(1215 Sqrt[2]), 0, 0}, {0, 1/(1215 Sqrt[2]), 0}, {0, 0, 1/(1215 Sqrt[2])}}
> ```

```
N[%]
```

> ```
> {{0.000581981, 0., 0.}, {0., 0.000581981, 0.}, {0., 0., 0.000581981}}
> ```

One workaround is to integrate manually:

```
M = {{y^2 + z^2, -x y, -y z}, {-y x, x^2 + z^2, -y z}, {-z x, -z y, x^2 + y^2}};
Integrate[M, {x, y, z} ∈ R]
```

> ```
> {{0.0471405, 0., 0.}, {0., 0.0471405, 0.}, {0., 0., 0.0471405}}
> ```